# Migrate Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.SQLStore to Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to update one of my **Xamarin.Forms apps** that uses the **deprecated Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.SQLStore** pacakge with the new **Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore** package but I get the following error when I try to install the package in my Core pcl project:

```
Could not install package 'Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore 4.0.0'. 
You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. 
For more information, contact the package author.
```

I tried to follow [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-offline-data) but  they seem to forget to add the code sample, so I can't figure out exacly what they are doing. The deprecated Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.SQLStore package installed in a PCL library but the new Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore package doesn't or so it seems.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the dependencies on the Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SqLiteStore nuget package and make sure that you aren't violating any of them with your project targets (Properties > Library > Targeting > Targets).

You may have to try installing Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SqLiteStore v3.1.0 instead of 4.0.0

Comment: I don't believe it has anything to do with the package dependencies, otherwise the error message would say so. I am afraid this package is not compatible with pcl anymore which would make it useless to me. I was hoping someone had some experience with these packages or someone from MS could clarify this. I will try to install v3.1.0. If that doesn't work I will try to download the package, unzip it and have a look at its definition to see what exactly it supports.

Comment: @chriszumberge  you were right about installing v3.1.0

Comment: The package dependencies section tells you what profile of PCL it's compatible with, if any at all

Comment: And where exactly do you find this dependencies section? I am using Xamarin Studio/Visual Studio for mac. I have seen the dependencies section on the nuget website but it doesn't say anything about PCL profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore 4.0.0 does not support PCL anymore but they moved to .NET Standard 1.4. PCL support stops at version 3.1.0

**So if you are using PCL install v3.1.0. But before you install v3.1.0, make sure you manually remove the deprecated Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.SQLStore first.**

Check out this issue for more details: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/issues/337

Answer (score 0):

you can try and open the .csproj of your PCL and replace the `Profile78` entry with a profile the NuGet package supports (probably `Profile259` which includes almost everything but windows phone silverlight)

If your project won't compile after changing your profile (because there are missing type references e.g.) try picking a different profile the package supports.

If you're having multiple PCLs you might need to change the target profile of all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing .Net profile to **Profile 7** and then update.
Go To **Cross Platforms Project Options->Build->General->.Net Portable**